# Calculate Amount (Qty * Price) in SQL query or UI Code

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

In the below query, i just fetch the Item details with its qty 
and rate (qty and rates ate calculated based on some business logic, so that  using sub queries or aggregates).

```
SELECT  ItemID,
        ItemName,
        (...
        ...
        )   AS  ItemQty,
        (....
        ....
        )   AS  ItemPrice
FROM    ....
```

Now i need to list this details in a grid with `Amount` (ie `ItemQty * ItemPrice`).

```
Sample Output 
------
ItemId ItemName ItemQty ItemPrice Amount
1      ABC      10.0    22.5      225.0
2      PQR      12.35   156.5     1932.775
```

I have two options to calculate `Amount` (`ItemQty * ItemPrice`)

1. Calculate the amount in sql query itself

   using the entire sub queries again to multiply the values 
   or  an outer select query to calculate the same
2. use the UI/code part to calculate the ItemQty * ItemPrice while binding the data to grid.

In this which one i can follow?

Comment: The above query is just a sample to shown the scenario.

Comment: Sample data and the query what you have tried will be more helpful !!

Comment: @Suraz, thanx , sample output added, but the question is simple, where can i calculate the Amount(Qty*Rate) in sql query itself or in UI code part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should isolate the logic by doing it in UI.

[Is SQL code faster than C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974867/is-sql-code-faster-than-c-sharp-code)

This link explains well for your question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @abdul-rasheed , in the given link i liked "Aristos" answer this is what i wanted to say.

Comment: @KumarHars, thank u for your suggestion, i got mix on answers , so i need some time to read each and every answers and links to conclude to a solution,

Answer (score 2):

if you are using property in code then make use property to calculate.
Though it depend upon your query also.

i) Suppose one query do not calculate and resultset return is 200 .

ii) Calculated query return 100 rows.

in option i) 100 rows is extra because you need additional info to calculate.

In this scenario calculation should be done in proc itself.

In case both option return 100 rows then do calculation part in UI.

Comment: So your suggestion is , do the calculation in UI part ( the records return in the result set will be always same in both case, no additional records for calculation)?

Comment: Yes.Preferred way will be using propert, so that same code is reuse in several places.

Answer (score 0):

Give it to the SQL and it will be faster.
If you give UI thread, the browser may freeze based number of rows.
And don't use subqueries and always try for SQL joins.

```
SELECT  ItemID,
        ItemName,
        ItemQty,
        ItemPrice
        (ItemQty * ItemPrice) as Amount
FROM    table

 SELECT  ItemID,
            ItemName,
            table1.ItemQty,
            table2.ItemPrice
            (table1.ItemQty * table2.ItemPrice) as Amount
    FROM    table inner join ....
            table2 inner join ....
            table3
```

Assuming, table1 has Qty details and table2 has price details.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the amount in the UI / Backend code because the qty and price  will be display as well in the grid. you can apply some business logic with the computation of the amount without affecting the performance of your sql script.